# How to get records between 24 and 36 hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records between 24 and 36 hours.

So far I have :

```
select * from tablename where DATEDIFF(DAY, dateColumn, GETDATE())>0
```

This returns me all records older than 24 hours. I am looking to get records older than 24 but no older than 36.

Thanks

Comment: title says 48 and test 36.

Answer (score 5):

So far all the answer here do something like `WHERE a.function(date_field) > 0`; they place a function around your search field.

Unfortunately this means that the RDBMS's optimiser ***can not*** use any index on that field.

Instead you may be recommended in moving the calculations "to the right hand side".

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
      dateColumn >= DATEADD(HOUR, -36, GETDATE())
  AND dateColumn <  DATEADD(HOUR, -24, GETDATE())
```

This format calculates two values, once, and then can do a range seek on an index.  Rather than scanning the whole table, repeating the same calculations again and again.

Comment: Do we need to define DATEADD function? @MatBailie

Answer (score 2):

Note: While these are the first solutions to come to mind, they are suboptimal as pointed out in the comments. See @MatBailie's answer for a solution that would be preferable.

While these are natural and might be okay in some limited use, you really should prefer a solution that is  [Search ARGument ABLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

> Sargable
>
> In relational databases, a condition (or predicate) in a
>   query is said to be sargable if the DBMS engine can take advantage of
>   an index to speed up the execution of the query. The term is derived
>   from a contraction of Search ARGument ABLE.

Original answers:

Just add another condition:

```
select * 
  from tablename 
 where DATEDIFF(DAY, dateColumn, GETDATE())>0
   and DATEDIFF(HOUR, dateColumn, GETDATE()) <= 36
```

or

```
select * 
  from tablename 
 where DATEDIFF(HOUR, dateColumn, GETDATE()) BETWEEN 24 AND 36
```

Note: In addition to being non-sargable this BETWEEN also includes records 24 hours old when in fact OP askks for  wants older than 24. [OP use between a couple times, but clarifies that it isn't an inclusive SQL BETWEEN, but rather a semi-inclusive between that must be implemented with > and <=. ]

Comment: -1 : Please note, this is not "SARGable", by which I mean it will destroy an ability to use indexes; you will always get a full scan.  Arithmetic manipulation of the formulae can mean that you don't need to wrap the dateColumn in functions, and get a range-seek instead.

Comment: @MatBailie Great point. Suggest the SARGable alternative you have in mind? That'll get there faster than my edit.

Comment: @KarlKieninger - I also posted an answer that contains that code.

Comment: @KarlKeininger - There are two differences.  `BETWEEN` is `>= AND <=` but I use `>= AND <`  that way you get exactly 12 hours of results.  *(Just like not counting both midnights when looking at a whole day)*.  The other is that I have `field >= f(x) AND field < g(x)`  but you have `f(field) >= x AND f(field) <= y`.  That's the big difference because the optimiser ***can't*** "see through the function" to see what range of dateField values will satisfy it, so it can't use an Index.  My answer allows use of an index by not wrapping the search field in a function.

Comment: Please note, your second option is still not SARGable.  By putting `dateColumn` inside the function `DATEDIFF` you prevent that.  `field >= function(constant)` is SARGable, but `function(field) < constant` is not.

Comment: @MatBailie GOt it. I agree on both counts. I've up-voted yours and will edit mine to indicate that they while the are "natural" queries that might be okay for light/ad hoc use anything repeatable should be constructed as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You must also specify the 36 hours:

```
select * from tablename where DATEDIFF(DAY, dateColumn, GETDATE())>0 AND DATEDIFF(hh, dateColumn, GETDATE())<=36
```

Answer (score 0):

Use between:

```
select * from tablename where DATEDIFF(hour, dateColumn, GETDATE()) between 24 and 36
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE DATEDIFF(hh,dateColumn,GETDATE()) between 24 and 36
```